# How to hide and unhide combobox in html and jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

Below codes hide and unhide input type...., I need to hide and unhide combobox (select) what can I change there? I tried but there is no luck

```
    <table>
    <?php
    for($count=0;$count<=2;$count++)
    {
     echo"<tr>
        <td>
          <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"sd3\" value=\"mfi_nam9\" class=\"checkme\" />
        </td>
        <td>First Value</td>
        <td>
          <input type=\"number\" name=\"mfi_nam9\" class=\"text1 required\" id=\"mfi_name\" hidden>
        </td>
        <td>
    <td>
    <select name=\"ItemCode\" class=\"text\" hidden>
    <option value=\"001\">Item 1</option>
    <option value=\"002\">Item 2</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</td>
      </tr>";
    }
      ?>

    </table>



    <script>
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.checkme[type="checkbox"]'), function(elem) {
      elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.text1[type="number"]').hidden = !this.checked;
      });
    })
    </script>


    <script>
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.checkme[type="checkbox"]'), function(elem) {
      elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.text[type="select"]').hidden = !this.checked;
      });
    })
    </script>
```

I even tried to change to type["select"] but it does not work
Please anyone can help me

Comment: You have a hidden attribute (hardcoded) on the combobox. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes I have to hide it as I hid textbox, when I check checkbox it unhides textbox I want to be same to combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector is not correct: `.text[type="select"]`, it should be replaced with : `select.text` .

Please note that you have some mistakes in your HTML: the same `id` cannot be used several times, and there is an extra `td` tag (`<td><td>` instead of `<td`>).

Your Javascript can also be simplified.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="sd3" value="mfi_nam9" class="checkme" /></td>
        <td>First Value</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="mfi_nam9" class="text1 required" hidden></td>
        <td>
            <select name="ItemCode" class="text" hidden>
                <option value="001">Item 1</option>
                <option value="002">Item 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="sd3" value="mfi_nam9" class="checkme" /></td>
        <td>First Value</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="mfi_nam9" class="text1 required" hidden></td>
        <td>
            <select name="ItemCode" class="text" hidden>
                <option value="001">Item 1</option>
                <option value="002">Item 2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.checkme[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.addEventListener('change', function () {
            this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.text1[type="number"]').hidden = !this.checked;
            this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('select.text').hidden = !this.checked;
        });
    });
</script>
```